# Como agrupar valores e processa-las para o BD?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Tenho um BD que contém 16 campos de informações, este BD guarda apostas efetuadas em um sistema, pra posteriormente poder processar o resultado e pagamento do bilhete do cliente.

Na parte de administração, o ADM tem uma área onde é possível colocar os resultados do jogos que foram efetuados pelo cliente, quando o cliente efetua uma aposta, é armazenado o nome do time, o tipo de aposta, e o confronto.

Por exemplo, tem um jogo de Vasco e Flamengo, você aposta que o Vasco vai fazer 2 gols no segundo tempo, no BD eu armazeno estas informações da seguinte maneira:

***Nome do time: Vasco.***

***Tipo de aposta: +2.***

***Confronto: Vasco x Flamengo.***

Na parte administrativa, o ADM tem que conferir todos os jogos que estão no BD, só que vários clientes faz o mesmo tipo de aposta, ou seja, terei no BD 15,20 registros repetidos, com o mesmo ***Nome do time***, mesmo ***Tipo de aposta*** e mesmo ***Confronto***.

O Administrador, faz as conferência dos jogos, por um *`select`*, eu imprimo todos os registros do BD em uma, a select tem 3 opções, *"ganhou, perdeu, cancelado"*. e pela ID do registro daquele confronto, eu consigo atualizar o resultado no BD.

Mas o problema, é que tem muitos resultados repetidos, e fica complicado para o administrador colocar o mesmo resultado em vários jogos iguais, exemplo:
[image: Print do sistema com jogos repetidos]

O Que eu quero, é agrupar estes jogos, baseado no mesmo confronto,Condição aposta e Aposta, e o resultado que o administrador colocar no select, valha para todos do mesmo grupo, sem que seja preciso colocar o mesmo resultado várias vezes.
Em `PHP` eu consigo agrupar no `sql`:

```
$conexao->prepare('SELECT time_apostado,tipojogo,tipoaposta,codigo  FROM bilhetes_temp WHERE codigo GROUP BY time_apostado,tipojogo,tipoaposta');
```

Mas não faço a mínima de ideia de como mostrar apenas 1 resultado para o admin, e fazer com que o o resultado da select que ele colocar, valha para todos os outros que são iguais.

Então, alguém me dar uma ideia de como eu agrupo esses resultados no `PHP` ou também no `JasvaScript`?

Comment: Não entendi bem como você pretende agrupar esse resultado. Pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Quero agrupa-los em uma única select, para que seja possível o administrador inserir o resultado em uma só, e o mesmo valer para os resultados repetidos.

Comment: Só para entender melhor... o administrador vai colocar o resultado do jogo certo? Ai com esse resultado original ele fará a seleçao doa apostadores que acertaram o resultado... eh isso que vc quer?

Comment: Se for isso... voce tem que criar uma tabela a parte .. tipo resultado_original e ai compara-la com a tabela das apostas para selecionar apenas as apostas dos ganhadores. se precisar eu faço a resposta para você

Comment: Voce também pode criar um campo na tabela chamado status.. se for 0 é que ainda esta em verificação... se for 1 é que o usuario acertou... se for 2 é que o usuario errou... assim quando o administrador postar o resultado real do jogo.. ele fara um UPDATE na tabela aonde o resultado original for = ao resultado dos apostadores... com isso vc fara um unico select na mesma tabela aonde todas as apostas tem o status = 1... se quiser posso criar este exemplo

Comment: André, isto eu já fiz, 0 para perdeu e 1 para ganhou, só que o sistema contem muitos jogos repetidos, então eu queria que quando houvesse por exemplo; dois jogos com os mesmos valores, então além de mostrar ao admin esses dois jogos repetidos, queria que aparecesse só 1, nesse '1' ele colocaria o resultado se ganhou ou perdeu, daí o script daria o UPDATE em todos os jogos que forem iguais, ou seja do mesmo tipo de aposta, sem que fosse preciso ele colocar várias vezes o resultado em jogos repetidos. deu pra entender?

Comment: Sim... acho que entendi... mas soh acho que vc nao esta otimizando seu codigo... veja... ao inves de o admin selecionar 1 para dizer que todos os jogos com aquele tal resultado ganhou... o administrador simplesmente posta o resultado do jogo em um formulario e em outro aquivo vc resgata estes valores e automaticamente altera em todos WHERE resultado = $_POST.... oque vc acha?

Comment: Nao sei se na tabela existe esse campo... mas acho interessante cada jogo ter uma nuneraçao unica... por exemplo... flamengo x santos... jogo de numero: 5... vasco x palmeiras... jogo de numero 6... assim vc pode fazer o GROUP BY do jeito que vc esta querendo pois vc agrupa as apostas pelo numero do jogo... no caso jogos do vasco x palmeiras ficaria GROUP BY numero_jogo 6

Comment: já resolveu @CassianoJosé essa questão? Chegou a testar a solução que postei como resposta ?

Comment: Funcionou certinho! muito obrigado SneepS e desculpa à demora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da para fazer um tabela dentro de outra tabela, seria tipo um 'detalhes' para cada resultado que for igual, veja um exemplo de um plugin [jqWidget](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/nestedgrids.htm):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com um pouco de paciência consegui usar para agrupar por código:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue um exemplo codificado do uso do plugin:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title id='Description'>This example shows how to display nested Grid plugins.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/demos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = "../sampledata/employees.xml";
            var source =
            {
                datafields: [
                    { name: 'FirstName' },
                    { name: 'LastName' },
                    { name: 'Title' },
                    { name: 'Address' },
                    { name: 'City' }
                ],
                root: "Employees",
                record: "Employee",
                id: 'EmployeeID',
                datatype: "xml",
                async: false,
                url: url
            };
            var employeesAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
            var orderdetailsurl = "../sampledata/orderdetails.xml";
            var ordersSource =
            {
                datafields: [
                    { name: 'EmployeeID', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipName', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipAddress', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipCity', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipCountry', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShippedDate', type: 'date' }
                ],
                root: "Orders",
                record: "Order",
                datatype: "xml",
                url: orderdetailsurl,
                async: false
            };
            var ordersDataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(ordersSource, { autoBind: true });
            orders = ordersDataAdapter.records;
            var nestedGrids = new Array();
            // create nested grid.
            var initrowdetails = function (index, parentElement, gridElement, record) {
                var id = record.uid.toString();
                var grid = $($(parentElement).children()[0]);
                nestedGrids[index] = grid;
                var filtergroup = new $.jqx.filter();
                var filter_or_operator = 1;
                var filtervalue = id;
                var filtercondition = 'equal';
                var filter = filtergroup.createfilter('stringfilter', filtervalue, filtercondition);
                // fill the orders depending on the id.
                var ordersbyid = [];
                for (var m = 0; m < orders.length; m++) {
                    var result = filter.evaluate(orders[m]["EmployeeID"]);
                    if (result)
                        ordersbyid.push(orders[m]);
                }
                var orderssource = { datafields: [
                    { name: 'EmployeeID', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipName', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipAddress', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipCity', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShipCountry', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShippedDate', type: 'date' }
                ],
                    id: 'OrderID',
                    localdata: ordersbyid
                }
                var nestedGridAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(orderssource);
                if (grid != null) {
                    grid.jqxGrid({
                        source: nestedGridAdapter, width: 780, height: 200,
                        columns: [
                          { text: 'Ship Name', datafield: 'ShipName', width: 200 },
                          { text: 'Ship Address', datafield: 'ShipAddress', width: 200 },
                          { text: 'Ship City', datafield: 'ShipCity', width: 150 },
                          { text: 'Ship Country', datafield: 'ShipCountry', width: 150 },
                          { text: 'Shipped Date', datafield: 'ShippedDate', width: 200 }
                       ]
                    });
                }
            }
            var photorenderer = function (row, column, value) {
                var name = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', row).FirstName;
                var imgurl = '../../images/' + name.toLowerCase() + '.png';
                var img = '<div style="background: white;"><img style="margin:2px; margin-left: 10px;" width="32" height="32" src="' + imgurl + '"></div>';
                return img;
            }
            var renderer = function (row, column, value) {
                return '<span style="margin-left: 4px; margin-top: 9px; float: left;">' + value + '</span>';
            }
            // creage jqxgrid
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: 850,
                height: 365,
                source: source,
                rowdetails: true,
                rowsheight: 35,
                initrowdetails: initrowdetails,
                rowdetailstemplate: { rowdetails: "<div id='grid' style='margin: 10px;'></div>", rowdetailsheight: 220, rowdetailshidden: true },
                ready: function () {
                    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('showrowdetails', 1);
                },
                columns: [
                      { text: 'Photo', width: 50, cellsrenderer: photorenderer },
                      { text: 'First Name', datafield: 'FirstName', width: 100, cellsrenderer: renderer },
                      { text: 'Last Name', datafield: 'LastName', width: 100, cellsrenderer: renderer },
                      { text: 'Title', datafield: 'Title', width: 180, cellsrenderer: renderer },
                      { text: 'Address', datafield: 'Address', width: 300, cellsrenderer: renderer },
                      { text: 'City', datafield: 'City', width: 170, cellsrenderer: renderer }
                  ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
    <div id="jqxgrid">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```